# Catch Or Detect ANR Exception

Tags: android, crash, detect

I wanna send /data/anr/traces.txt if app ever crashed, but the question is how can I know my app crashed before.

```
    File file = new File("/data/anr/traces.txt");
    if (file.exists()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra("subject", file.getName());
        intent.putExtra("body", "...");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file));

        if (file.getName().endsWith(".gz")) {
            intent.setType("application/x-gzip");
        } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
            intent.setType("text/plain");
        } else {
            intent.setType("application/octet-stream");
        }

                    // ? Can I send it without permission?
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively you can use ACRA http://code.google.com/p/acra/. It will enable you to get crash reports directly to your app server/third party server.

Comment: BTW, Is ACRA crash reports the same with traces.txt?

Comment: @thecr0w: This link - https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog ,also helps to detect ANR in android app as well

Answer (score 6):

One reliable method is to use a "dirty bit"; write a value to a file when your app starts, and write a different value to the file when it shuts down cleanly. Each time your app starts, check what's in the file before writing to it; if it's not the value you write when the app shuts down cleanly, you know the app crashed.